# why viewmodel obj is null in the controller?

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core

I want to pass the form value in my controller. but it is null. I am not able to find the issue.i need to pass the viewmodel object from view to the controller . and obj property is null.I have given below each model and code I have written

This is my viewmodel:

```
{ 
      public customer customer {get ; set ; }
      public student student {get ; set ; }
}
```

My student model

```
{ 
      public string studentId {get ; set ; }
      public string studentname {get ; set ; }
}
```

My customer model

```
{ 
      public string customerId {get ; set ; }
      public stringcustomername {get ; set ; }
}
```

This code is in my controller

```
public IActionResult Add(viewmodel obj)
{
    obj is null
}
```

View:

```
<div class ='row'>
<div class='col-md-6'>
<form id="myform">
    <input asp-for="customer.customername" class="form-control form-control-sm" />
    <span asp-validation-for="customer.customername" class="text-danger"></span>

    <input asp-for="student.studentname" class="form-control form-control-sm" />
    <span asp-validation-for="student.studentname" class="text-danger"></span>
</form>
</div>
<div class='col-md-6'>
<button id='add'>add</button>
</div>
</div>
```

And this is in my `.js` file

```
$('#add').click(() => {
    $.ajax({
        url: "/controller/Add",
        method: "POST",
        data: $("#myform").serialize()
    })
})
```

Comment: Hi @Sumit Roy, In your view I do not see any element's `id` called myform`$("#myform")`.

Comment: sorry ,i have written it wrong

Comment: Hi @Submit Roy,what is your whole controller?Did your controller have [ApiController] or not?What about adding [FromForm] in your action's parameter?

Comment: You could check the gif here:https://i.stack.imgur.com/66i9w.gif ,it actually works well.

Comment: Thanks, Now i need to figure out my problem .How to accept your and here ?

Comment: No need here.It's just a comment not an answer.Wish you could find your issue!I suggest that you could add `console.log($("#myform").serialize())` to check what is your post data and you could see the log in Console panel when you F12 in the browswer.

Comment: ok thanks mate , you saved me ..i will check mine .. if not solved will connect you

Comment: Ok fine.May you succeed.

Comment: Hei @Rena its working :) Thanks a lot .you saved me .how can I contact you if get stuck? :p I have to submit a project on Monday :(

Comment: the first thing you need to do is to learn how to write `C#` using good conventions, class names and public property names should all be in `PascalCase`. That's simple but important to prove that you want to learn C#, you really love it and you treat it as an art, not a non-sense programming language.